# Как изменения в бд применить к django models

Tags: python, django, postgresql

С помощью веб приложения создал ER диаграмму, сгенерировал из неё скрипт postgresql. В итоге у меня есть готовые таблицы в postgres. С помощью команды

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

создал из таблиц django модели. При изменении сущностей в ER моделях -> в таблицах postgres нужно изменения применить к django models.
Как это можно сделать?

Пробовал накатить миграцию

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

думал, это должно изменить модели, но ничего не изменилось